# Theory of bijections witout finite orbits is complete.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Suppose I have a theory $T$ of a language $L$ consiting of one function symbol $f$ of arity one, that asserts that $f$ is a bijection with no finite oribits. How do I show that $T$ is complete?

$T$ can be written as the following axioms:
$$ (\forall x)((\exists y) f(y)=x)$$
$$ (\forall x)((\forall y) (f(x)=f(y)\rightarrow x=y))$$
$$ (\forall x)(f(x)\neq x)$$
$$ (\forall x)(f^2(x)\neq x)$$
$$\vdots$$

So my task is to show every sentence in $L$ can be either disproved or proved by these axioms (plus the usual axioms). This seems a hopelessly complicated task. I tried induction on constructing such sentences $p$ but couldn't get anywhere. Any idea?

Comment: Do you familiar with the concept of Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game

Comment: Maybe you can take a semantic approach, and work with the models.

Comment: Not quite sure how the game helps?

Comment: You can take the apporoch of @realdonaldtrump, and by the completness theorem it's enough to show that any two models are elementary equivalence. One basic tool for it is using EF games.

Comment: still not getting it

Comment: If you learn this subject, I strogly recommend to check your class notes (note that because you have a function-symbol you need to adopt the structure). If you didn't, then I don't know about it.

Comment: @Mathmo Try drawing a picture of a few countable models, to see what the different possibilities are. E-F games could be helpful, but it is possible to avoid them if you are not comfortable with them.

Comment: Each model just splits into orbits isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. What I don't see is how to translate this into the elementary equivalence. Even in the simple case of two orbits versus one orbit.

Comment: Designing a quantifier elimination algorithm for your theory is fairly straightforward and leads to the desired result. I can give some more details if you are interested.

Comment: Yes please! That would be great.